# Error en testing de REST API Jest y Supertest

Tags: javascript, api, express, jest

Estoy tratando de testear una rest-api con jest y supertest pero me da error. Intente lo q expone supertest en su documentacion oficial pero no funciona, osea el test se completa como satisfactorio pero jest lanza errores en la consola. Además si cambio los datos esperados en .toEqual({}) igual se completa el test como satisfactorio aunque los datos estén mal. La app esta hecha con express y la base de datos es mongodb no se si haga falta solo les digo

#### Este es mi codigo actual

```
it("Get /users/:id ", ()=>{
              request(app)
                    .get('api/users/6169ec60ecf46765d56f2ac4"')
                    .end((err, res)=>{
                                if(err){
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    console.log(res);
                                    expect(res).toEqual({
                                        _id: "6169ec60ecf46765d56f2ac4",
                                        username: "Yusei-Updated",
                                        email: "updated@gmail.com",
                                        password: "ZeroUpdated",
                                        picture: "update.jpg",
                                    })
                                }
                            })

                        })
```

#### Tambien intenté esto que es como sale en la documentacion oficial y nada

```
 request(app)
            .get('api/users/6169ec60ecf46765d56f2ac4')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else
                {
                    expect(res).toEqual({
                        _id: "6169ec60ecf46765d56f2ac4",
                        username: "Yusei-Updated",
                        email: "updated@gmail.com",
                        password: "ZeroUpdated",
                        picture: "updated.jpg",
                        __v: 0
                    })
                }
            })
```

### Recordar

Que este es un archivo user.test.js y que todo lo anterior descrito está dentro de un

```
describe("Blablabla", ()=>{
  ....
  ....
})
```

Comment: No dejes la pregunta en suspenso: ¿qué errores estás teniendo? Explícalo brevemente tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Sencillamente  completa el test como ok pero lanza errores de consola señalando el  request(app).get() y si cambias los valores de la comparacion el test sigue como ok cuando en verdad deberia fallar, ademas sigue lanzando los errores señalando el codigo